# Adding an EPSG:2056 WMTS layer to Cesium

Tags: epsg, wmts, cesium, ol-cesium, tiling-scheme

I can implement EPSG:4326 WMTS layers to my Cesium App like this:

```
const imageryProvider = new this.Cesium.WebMapTileServiceImageryProvider({
        url: "https://openwms.domain.ch/service/wmts",
        layer: "layerName",
        style: "",
        tileMatrixSetID: "EPSG:4326:256",
        tileMatrixLabels: this.getTileMatrixLabels(),
        maximumLevel: 19,
        tilingScheme: new this.Cesium.GeographicTilingScheme()
});

const imageryLayer = new this.Cesium.ImageryLayer(imageryProvider);
scene.imageryLayers.add(imageryLayer);
```

But my normal WMTS layers are EPSG:2056. I could only find the two TilingSchemes:

- GeographicTilingScheme (EPSG:4326)
- WebMercatorTilingScheme (EPSG:3857)

How can I get my EPSG:2056 WMTS layers in Cesium? The options I could think of:

- Save all my layers (3k+) in EPSG:2056 and EPSG:4326
- Create an own TilingScheme for EPSG:2056.

How could I create an own TilingScheme? Does this make sense? Or is there a better way to deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kinda found a solution for this problem:
Since I used ol-cesium anyways, I had to use a version of ol-cesium with [this pullrquest](https://github.com/openlayers/ol-cesium/pull/690) merged in it. Ol-cesium in it's actual version shows WMS layers correctly but not WMTS layers.